# Can't understand how to use DevExpress tab control

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress

I can't get how to use DevExpress tab control. I dragged control and added three tabs, and when I try to put a content inside proper tags, it says that `DevExpress.Web.ASPxTabControl.Tab` doesn't have public property named `div`.

Here is the code:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="AddNews.aspx.cs" Inherits="MarketingAdmin.EditNews" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="DevExpress.Web.v12.1, Version=12.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a"
    Namespace="DevExpress.Web.ASPxTabControl" TagPrefix="dx" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="DevExpress.Web.ASPxEditors.v12.1, Version=12.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a"
    Namespace="DevExpress.Web.ASPxEditors" TagPrefix="dx" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="DevExpress.Web.ASPxHtmlEditor.v12.1, Version=12.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a"
    Namespace="DevExpress.Web.ASPxHtmlEditor" TagPrefix="dx" %>
<%@ Register assembly="DevExpress.Web.ASPxSpellChecker.v12.1, Version=12.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" namespace="DevExpress.Web.ASPxSpellChecker" tagprefix="dx" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
       <dx:ASPxTabControl ID="ASPxTabControl1" runat="server" ActiveTabIndex="0" 
        EnableTheming="True" Theme="Glass">
        <Tabs>
            <dx:Tab Text="Казахский" >
                <div style="font-family=Times New Roman; font-size:medium ">Категория 
        <asp:DropDownList ID="CategoryDropDownList" runat="server" 
            DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="id" ></asp:DropDownList> 
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MarketingConnectionString %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT [Name], [id] FROM [NewsCategory]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
    </div>
    <div style="font-family=Times New Roman; font-size:medium "> Заголовок 
        <asp:TextBox ID="TitleTextBox" runat="server" Width="610px"></asp:TextBox></div>

<dx:ASPxHtmlEditor ID="ASPxHtmlEditor1" runat="server">
</dx:ASPxHtmlEditor>            
            </dx:Tab>
            <dx:Tab Text="Русский">
            content 2
            </dx:Tab>
            <dx:Tab Text="Английский">
            content 3
            </dx:Tab>
        </Tabs>
    </dx:ASPxTabControl>


    <asp:Button ID="SaveButton" runat="server" Text="Сохранить" 
        onclick="SaveButton_Click" />
</asp:Content>
```

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what you're asking, I believe you need to use the [ASPxPageControl](http://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxperienceDemos/TabControl/Features.aspx).  The ASPxTabControl is only to create a tabstrip with no actual "tabs" below the strip.  It is best used for site navigation.